# Setting token balances in js test

Tags: solidity, testing, truffle-test

I want to be able to set the token balance for Alice to 500 DAI & 500 USDT, however I have no clue how I am going to do that.

Is there a way you can set an account's balance before a test without calling any functions?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referring to ERC20-based token balances (DAI, USDT), therefore, you can't set such as balances without defining the related contracts. However, it is not too complex. You can create a mock for these tokens, for instance, a DAI.sol contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.12;

import '@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol';

contract Dai is ERC20 {
    constructor () ERC20('DAI', 'Dai Stablecoin') public {}
    
    function faucet(address to, uint256 amount) external {
        _mint(to, amount);
    }
}
```

And then in your tests, you could simply add the amount of that token to Alice:

```
await dai.faucet(alice, web3.utils.toWei('1000'));
```